# How does IDE recognize compile time error internally?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

All the modern IDEs are intelligent enough to recognize the compile time error.
But i want to know how it internally solves it.
As before compilation all syntatic and symantic errors can not be resolved.
But it seems IDEs used it for recognizing the compile time error.

Let me know what is the internal implementation for this case. It Might be different for each IDE, then let me know with specific IDE.

Comment: They generally use an 'incremental compiler' to compile the code as you type.

Comment: Most modern IDE's know much more about the structure of your program than you immediately would expect.  This typically require a very tight integration with the compiler.  The Eclipse project even built their own compiler to get what they wanted.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen so you mean  to say that IDE(Eclipse in case) always at every moment when you write your code(Even a single letter) recompile the whole code and check for symantic and sytatic errors. It seems very exhausted process for the IDE. isn't it ?

Comment: @greg-449 your answer might be correct in case of single class.
but if in case of  multiple class project if we change a class and it affects to some other class then how IDE recognizes error in other class and show the error in IDE before Compile ??

Comment: The compiler maintains an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) telling it all about all the classes so it knows what needs to be done for any change. And, yes, this is a very complex process and sometimes may require quite a bit of work to be done in the background.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for sharing the link. Now i have the answer.

Comment: @JitendraYadav yes.  This is why you get red underlines in your IDE.